# Coin change,dynamic programming revisited

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am having tough time in understanding the logic behind this problem,
This is classical Dynamic Programming Problem

```
     Coin Change is the problem of finding the number 
     of ways of making changes for a particular amount of cents, n, 
     using a given set of denominations d1,d2,..dm;
```

I know how the recursion works,Like taking the mth coin or not.But I don't understand what does '+' do between the two states.

**For eg**

```
        C(N,m)=C(N,m-1)+C(N-dm,m)
                       ^
                       |
```

Question might be stupid but I still would like to know so that I can have better understanding.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , you haven't written your state right!
Coin Change:

Let C(i,j) represents the number of ways to form j as a sum using only i coins (from i to 1).

Now to get a recursive function you have to define transitions or change in state or may be just expressing the given expression in the terms of lower values!!

There are 2 **independent** ways in which I can represent this state that are

1) Lets pick up the i th coin , Then what happens ? I need denomination j-Denomination[i] with i-1 coins if repetition is not allowed .
i.e. C(i,j)= C(i-1,j-Denominations[i])

But wait , we are missing some ways i.e. when we do not take the current coin

2) C(i,j)=C(i-1,j)

Now as both of them are independent and exhaustive , These both of these state makes up the total number of ways!!!

C(i,j)=C(i-1,j)+C(i-1,j-Denominations[i])

I will leave the recurrence when repetition allowed for you!

Comment: "Now as both of them are independent and exhaustive "-this is the line I was looking for".Using '+' in between is same as we do or in combinatorics? that is "either this or that" way

Comment: Yes exactly!! Either this way or that !! No other possible ways and no repetition!!

Comment: Thanks a lot ...You helped a lot :)

Comment: Do understand by independent I mean independent ways to make the current state!! And not independency of both from each other